# Pop up warning your flash player maybe out of date

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-4

In my office, it seems the router is infected by malware. So when we access google.com and other specific sites, it always show pop up "warning!your flash player maybe out of date", then it will redirect to flash download page. I already downloaded it, the file is setup.exe. And because of my stupidity, I tried to run it. I don't know whether my phone  now is infected by this malware or not. And most important thing, if it is infected, how to fix it?
I read on internet, to fix the trouble we have to reset the router. But tjis is to fix the router. How about our phone? Is it already infected ? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you did is download an .exe file, you've nothing to worry about. It's a program for Windows, and it can't run on your Android phone. Just delete the file you downloaded to make sure no one copies it to a Windows computer by accident.

But if your router is infected by malware, don't use it at all. It can intercept and impersonate every website you use and visit. It can steal any login details you enter on websites and pretend to be you.

Comment: Hi Dan, but even I not connected to the router, I also cannot access google.com. It always redirected to flash page download. I use firefox browser.

Comment: As temporary solution, you can use [startpage](https://startpage.com/), it make google research via ixquick's servers.

Comment: If your computer do the redirect, it mean it's infected.

Comment: Ok, I've found the solution..after I cleared private data of browser, I can browse google properly now.